# Can there ever be any more angels, demons, or monsters?

Tags: supernatural

Within the *Supernatural* universe, the supernatural creatures fall into three groups:

- Angels, created by God at the beginning of time,
- Demons, created by Lucifer to populate Hell once he had fallen, and
- Monsters, created by Eve on a seemingly-continuous basis

> As of the end of season 6, God has vanished, Lucifer is locked in his
>  cage, and Eve is dead. Does this mean that there won't ever be any
>  "new" monsters, angels, or demons?

I'm particularly curious about the angels. I got the impression that God created a finite number of them "in the beginning", and then stopped. They all seem to know each other and consider themselves one big extended family. But during the last few seasons they have been killing each other off in droves. Does that mean that the number of angels has been dropping and has no chance of rebounding?

The demons and monsters, I'm less clear about; can Lucifer still create new demons from his cage? Will there ever be any new species of monster? (I assume that the existing populations can continue to procreate in whatever way they normally do.)

Comment: There is a small point at the end there which the answers aren't addressing.  You also ask if we'll see new types of monsters (e.g. Jefferson Starships), which I don't think we will, due to Lilith being gone.

Comment: @Keen Actually, Thaddeus's answer surmises that there may be other things besides Eve that are capable of creating monsters, which I assume is based on something we saw in one of the S7 episodes though I admit I don't remember it...

Comment: I don't recall there being any in-show evidence for that.

Comment: @Keen There isn't.  Eve was called the "Mother of All", and besides God, is the only known being that can create entirely new monsters.  I suspect it comes from the (pulled out of nowhere) theory that she's Leviathan, when the proof generally points away from that.

Comment: to be perfectly fair there is no real evidence that eve is dead.  The dragons summoned her from purgatory and shoved her essence into a virgin the Winchesters killed her host body but what eve was is a monster and where do monsters go when they die

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The Supernatural Universe would give you the impression that there is a limited amount of anything associated with the spiritual or supernatural realm of existence. That is a misnomer perpetuated by the very nature of the medium we use to watch the show. If the show ran for another twenty years, we would have no shortage of monsters, angels, or demons for Hunters to battle valiantly against.**

Here's why:

### **Angels**

- Whenever we see Angels, for example, they all appear to know each other and so when they die or are destroyed, they all appear bereaved (unless they are less than sane).
- What we fail to remember is this: there are countless Angels populating the heavens. Their apparent familiarity is due to their limited omniscience of each other.
- All Angels are aware of every other Angel, and this is key, **when they put their mind to the task.**
- So to our human minds, they appear to be a close and local family. But their family is far larger than we can comprehend and they have had millions of years to be acquainted and greater than human levels of comprehension to instantly interact.
- And even with all of that familiarity, they can still be surprised by the choices that other Angels make.
- With that said, there are likely to be millions of other Angels we haven't met and have chosen instead to keep their heads down during these events and insurrections caused by Micheal's, Gabriel's and Lucifer's struggles for power and dominance. There shouldn't be a shortage any time soon.

### **Demons**

Since the original pedigree of demons implies they were spawned originally by Lucifer, who was immediately locked up for transforming Lilith, there must be a method by which new demons are created that does not require the direct interaction of Lucifer.

- The show implies a demon was once a human soul that is tortured until their humanity is lost and they totally embrace being evil.
- There does not seem to be a lack of evil humans on Earth willing to trade their souls for power, make deals with demons or are so unrepentantly evil that Hell cannot make further use of them, our Demon supply should be not only constant but growing.
- Fortunately for us, Demons don't like or trust each other, so they are just as inclined to kill each other as us, a built-in population-limiting factor.

### **Monsters**

Yes, EVE was called the Mother of Monsters. But given what was hiding in Purgatory during the Leviathan Saga, there are likely plenty of other monsters and creators of monsters we have not met yet.

- They are likely hiding on other continents, in other religions, in other mythologies feasting upon the tender and delicious sweetbreads, spiritual effluvia, blood, semen, psychic energies, petty fears and anything else that makes Humans such a tasty monster chow.
- I am pretty certain they breed faster than Hunters can kill them. Most seem to come with their own built in propagation systems (vampires create new vampires by biting them, werewolves create new ones with a scratch or bite) so they don't need a Monster Creator like EVE to keep producing new ones.

### **Ghosts**

> A ghost or spirit remains connected to the mortal realm because it is attached to it through unfinished business or an unwillingness to move on. They may, as Dean nearly did and Bobby did do, refuse to accompany the Reaper who is tasked to help them move on. Many have a desire for revenge against those who they perceive to have caused their deaths, or will target people like them. Others like Dr Ellicott, Dr. H.H. Holmes, and Nurse Glockner were evil in life and continued this after death.

- Ghosts can be harmless or malevolent. Given the number of ghosts the Winchesters have had to dispatch, it is the rare ghost that is NOT trying to kill them. Since ghosts are human souls that have not moved on, there should be no lack of them.
- Demons are not "super-charged" ghosts. The method of destroying a spirit works on Demons **whose physical remains can be found** because the demon is the spirit of a human who has been corrupted and has lost all sense of its humanity. If you can find their bones, sanctifying/purifying those bones will work just like on any other spirit.
- But demons are much higher on the spiritual food chain and far more dangerous. Powers that ghosts may manifest with a bit of practice are part and parcel of the demonic package. This includes possession, telekinesis, superhuman strength during possession, awareness of other supernatural beings.

The beauty of Supernatural is they have created a show where they can always plumb another religion or society's supernatural realm for entirely new breeds of monsters unfamiliar to their viewing public. I give them good marks for the range of creatures and their willingness to experiment. When the show ends, it will be missed.

Comment: The last paragraph isn't entirely true.  They already had an [episode of other religions' gods](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Hammer_of_the_Gods) (including the reveal that Loki/the Trickster is actually the angel Gabriel), and showed them to be not just inferior, but the gods themselves fall under monster-of-the-week.  Kind of bland, really.

Comment: Oh, and ghosts aren't monsters, they fall under the same banner as demons.  [Demons are basically super-charged ghosts](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=6.04_Weekend_At_Bobby%27s).

Comment: Ghosts aren't monsters proper, not in the sense that they can trace a lineage back to Eve. They're just the lingering souls of the dead, not even necessarily malevolent.

Comment: @Izkata gods of other religions that have no contemporary worshipers (or very few of them) its canon that the souls of entities in the supernatural verse have some sort of energy associated with them that certain entities can access

Comment: @ThaddeusHowze Recent Supernatural episodes have provided new info on the number of Angels. Perhaps an update of the answer would be in order?

Answer (score 1):

Demons are created by a soul going to Hell, and being tortured there long enough that they conform to Hell's expectations of their behavior. Since people are still going to hell, either through deals made with crossroads demons, or more commonly just being evil bastards, there will always be a new supply. (Though the oldest demons, the most powerful, are limited in supply... and probably all dead already).

Angels, on the other hand, may be finite in number. And other than Castiel, we've never seen them resurrected either. At the moment, we only know of 3 that are alive. Though possibly more are in hiding.

Monsters are self-sustaining. Vampires can create new vampires, ghouls create new ghouls, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Its never actually stated if angels can procreate or not (with each other to create another angel there was that half angel episode)

demons are corrupted human souls so as long as humanity exists there can be more demons

the monsters that turn humans would be the same as demons

as to new species I might have to re-watch the episodes but is there any real evidence that eve is actually dead they destroyed her body but she was still a monster and monsters go to purgatory when they die

Answer (score 0):

I am in no way shape or form associated with the show but from what I've seen they tend to incorporate monsters and other beings from historic folklore or myths of our world and there are no specific beings that are solely created for the show itself.  I don't think they will make up any new folklore but I don't see how it is unlikely that any form of monster from the folklore and myths that as humans we have come up with should not be fair game for the show to include. If anything they could always just add to the plot and say one of them created the monsters before they died or were caged up in case of Lucifer. Or incorporate a new Creator  of some form, personally I'd use an angel who can safely use mass amounts of souls, kind of like how Cas did before he blew up. Or they could just bring god back into the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby explains in season 3 that she became a demon after living as a human, and still remembers what is like to be human. This leads me to believe that all demons are created from humans, but because of living as evil beings in hell for so long, they lose their sense of humanity and become truly evil beings, which is what happens to most demons. This could also mean the same things of angels, and from what I gather, monsters reproduce similarly to humans, which is explained in many episodes throughout the season. I don't see a mass extinction of demons, angels, it monsters at any point prior to the inevitable end of the world.

Answer (score 0):

There can be new "species" of monsters, both in sense of "never seen before on the show" and also "didn't exist yesterday". The story seems to be borrowing the diety power concept from American Gods, where the gods in America seem to be depowered, or willing to take similar forms. They still exist, even though Gabriel was pretending to be a Norse God, and there are still untapped mythos from Hindu, South American and other cultures. While they heavily depend on JudeoChristian mythos, they leave other fantastical options open, such as Death incarnate and the Djinn. 
Supernatural also don't seem to mind integrating different planes, showing multiple versions of Hell, Purgatory, Oz and Variations of Heaven, so exploring various other planes of existance are not out of the question either. There's a whole world of potential monsterness out there.

Answer (score 0):

**Demons** are created from years and years of a soul's torment in hell. Demons are just human souls that have been tortured in hell, so demons are always in the making. Most **Monsters** can breed to make more, or turn others. Of course, creating more **Pureblood Monsters** proves more than difficult, but normal monsters? Definitely. **Angels**, however, are a more difficult subject. They, to the best of our knowledge, can only be created by God, or someone with equal power to God, so the chances that more angels will be made seems slimmer.

Comment: Can you provide any sources which support the above information?